# Android: Image does not adjust on Galaxy Nexus and Nexus 4 (both xhdpi) but does perfectly on Nexus 7 (also xhdpi)?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-drawable

I am making an android app that displays an image in the main activity. To adjust the size of this image on different screen size devices I made different drawable folders and added images of corresponding resolutions. In android studio the image is perfectly fitting on Nexus 7 device (1200x1920; xhdpi) but is too big for the GalaxyNexus and Nexus 4 which are also xhdpi devices. Why is this so? Can somebody suggest a way to fix this problem? Thanks in advance !!

```
<ImageView
 android:id="@+id/imageView1"
 android:src="@drawable/img"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: I suggest you read more carefully the guides. DPI and resolution are very different things. DPI is density of pixels, and resolution is total number of pixels.

Comment: are you using ImageView to display the image?  What are you using for scaleType attribute?

Comment: @CSmith yes I am using Imageview. I have added the edit above.

Comment: please debug it with giving a fixed width and height

Comment: @kukku But that would change the dimension on all screens?

Comment: you told that you have created separated xml file for each resolutions right ?

Comment: @kukku no, i didn't say that !!

Comment: sorry,ok then you can create separate xml layout for each screen as you want

Comment: I, got the fix btw, I have added the answer !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the fix finally. This can be taken care of using another folder drawable-large-xhdpi for the tablet.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that a 2013 Nexus 7 and the Nexus 4 are both XHDPI devices. That means that the system will not perform any scaling on the image that you place into the drawable-xhdpi resource directory on either device, but that doesn't mean the image should just be displayed as-is.

The 4.7" @ 768x1280px (384x640dp) N4 is not the same as the 7" @ 1200x1920px (600x960dp) N7.

Whilst the density resource qualifier generally works well for things like icons, it alone isn't always enough to provide a responsive layout.

What is the image, and how will it be used? Is it a large background image / full screen image?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It isn't a background image. The image will occupy a portion of the screen. And there are textviews below the screen related to the image.